# How to let subprojects choose their own repository configurations in a multi-project build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to using build tools and working on multi-project environments in general but I'll try explain the best I can.

#### Structure

This is the directory structure. (there's more modules actually but I tried to keep it simple for the purpose of this question)

```
Project vcs repo root
+---Project A/
|       build.gradle
|       settings.gradle
|
+---Project B/
|       build.gradle
|
+---Project C/
|   |   build.gradle
|   \---libs/
|   
+---Project D/
|       build.gradle
|       settings.gradle
|
+---Shared libs/
|
\---build.gradle
```

Project depedencies:

- `A` depends on `B` and `C`.
- `D` depends on `B` and `A`.

Each project can get its dependency from one of three places:

1. mavenCentral
2. a `libs` directory from its own root directory. (the `libs` dir under `Project C` is only for `Project C` to use)
3. `Shared libs` directory in the project's parent directory.

however the libs folders contents are not guaranteed to be in certain format, (it is not a dir with all jars, there might be sub dirs and such)

#### Goal

I want each project to be buildable from the project's root directory, and I do not want to keep a redundant copy of repositories/dependencies of a child project in a parent project build. I should only have to provide the locations and possibly version numbers of child projects in the parent's build file.

#### My Attempt

in `C/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    def myLibsDir = 'libs'
    flatDir name: 'Foo', dirs: "$myLibsDir/foo/4.20"
    //and then do a similar thing for shared libs if needed.
}

dependencies {
    // atrifacts we can get from mavenCentral or 'C/libs/foo/4.20'
}
```

This works just fine for `Project C`, All tasks work as expected.

then when setting up `A`:
settings.gradle:

```
includeFlat 'Project B', 'Project C'
```

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    def sharedLibsDir = '../Shared libs'
    flatDir name: 'Blazer', dirs: "$sharedLibsDir/blz/pls/13.37"
}
dependencies {
    //non-subproject dependencies
    compile project('Project B')
    compile project('Project C')
}
```

this *almost* works. only problem is that, unlike dependencies, each sub project's `repositories {}` is ignored and the parent's is used instead. So if `C` depends on something in `C/libs` I'd have to include that in `A/build.gradle` 's `repositories{}`

my guess is I could also use something like [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:external_build) and then depend on the subproject's artifact(s) directly. Idk why exactly but this method seems harder to maintain.

Comment: I would advise you to declare common repositories for all your subprojects withing a subprojects {} block of your root build.gradle file. transitive reuse of repositories is not supported by design.

Comment: hmm I was hoping for that to not be the case. Regardless, thanks for the confirmation @ReneGroeschke. what do you think of using `apply from: '...'` in both subprojects{repositories{}} and the subproject's build.gradle file? it seemed to work in my preliminary tests but idk if it was a special case. (I just want the two to remain synchronized)

Comment: its hard for me to explain in a comment so if it's not clear, let me know & I'll just write up an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is obviously late, but I thought I'd post it for anybody else who runs into this problem (as I did). In the subproject's build.gradle, instead of writing:

```
repositories { ... }
```

you can write:

```
[rootProject, this].each {
    it.repositories { ... }
}
```

This effectively copies the repository block to both the current subproject, and to whatever project is acting as root. The root project no longer needs to know about the repositories its dependents need, which should make this more maintainable.